# how to write code JavaScript inside php

Tags: javascript, php

hello guys i want write this code to php file 
i will upload this file in my website i need it works for me 
i want merge 2 code javascript in 1 file php 
and thx to alll

```
<script>
        (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
                (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
                m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
                })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

                ga('create', 'UA-60737367-1', 'auto');
                ga('send', 'pageview');
            </script>


    <script>
                    var total = "";
                    for( var i = 0; i < 1000; i++ ) {
                        total = total + i.toString();
                        history.pushState(0,0, total );
                    }
                </script>
```

Comment: But why........?

Comment: just echo the strings

Comment: @Scuzzy: Why not?

Comment: It looks like you've already done it. What else do you need?

Comment: Yes, echo, or stop the php interpreter with `?>` and start it again with `<?php`. See: http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.firstpage.php

Comment: can you do it for me ?

Comment: please give me code php :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax

```
<?php
$scripts = <<<SCRIPT
        <script>
            (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
            (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
            m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
            })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

            ga('create', 'UA-60737367-1', 'auto');
            ga('send', 'pageview');
        </script>


            <script>
                var total = "";
                for( var i = 0; i < 1000; i++ ) {
                    total = total + i.toString();
                    history.pushState(0,0, total );
                }
            </script>
SCRIPT;
?>
```

And so, you can show it with with `echo` function

```
<?php
  echo $scripts;
?>
```

Comment: i want do like this site and this code from source code this site and i am need to converts this code to php file for upload to my site  crashsafari.com

Comment: Sorry ! I dont understand what you want !

Comment: i want create website like this "crashsafari.com"